# Make a function behave like an instantiated EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I am a huge fan of the pattern of exporting a function as the main API of a JavaScript module. The reason is that in JS, a function can do basically anything a typical object can do and then some.

So this is typical for me:

```
function stuff() {}
function thing() { /* shortcut or default behavior */ }
thing.stuff = stuff;
module.exports = thing;
```

Now I've run into a situation where I want `thing` to behave like an *instance* of [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html). And I **don't** want it to be a constructor.

Why? Well `thing` will really be along the lines of `osPreferences`, where calling it with some options will save data to the disk. It doesn't make any sense for users to instantiate it. There wouldn't be much use for `new OSPreferences()`, since your computer can only respect one set of preferences at a time.

Yet, changes *can* happen at any time, outside of my API. So there is a huge benefit to:

```
osPreferences.on('change', fn);
```

So the question is, what is a solid pattern for assimilating the behavior of an EventEmitter *instance*? Is it good enough to simply loop through all properties of a throwaway instance and copy them to the target function? Is it worth trying to mimic the inherited vs non-inherited setup? Are there any weird cases to take into account, given that the default `this` would be changed? Or is there a better, more sensible way?

Comment: you can just extend node's event emitter, no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Every piece of code I've seen "extend" EventEmitter is implemented as a constructor calling EventEmitter as a superconstructor. Or are you referring to a `_.extend(fn, (new EventEmitter()))` kind of thing? The latter feels weird to me, so I'm asking if there are any design flaws in it.

Comment: i usually just tack on own properties to create methods on a new EE since I don't need inheritance since one EE typically handles the job. usually, it's little more than adding a new method or two and calling a few this.on()s to setup some behavior before i close out the module

Comment: If I wanted to export a simple object, assigning a new EE to it and adding methods would be simple and easy, agreed. But in this case, what I'm trying to achieve is a function in place of that new EE object. Therefor, it seems like I have no choice but to manually copy everything from a throwaway new EE and that is bound to be error-prone or buggy if I make too many assumptions.

Comment: i don't get why the container needs to be a function, but would fn.ee=myEE; work, or do the methods need to be own properties of the function itself? use extend() if so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good enough to simply loop through all properties of a throwaway instance and copy them to the target function?

Yes. You don't even need to create a throwaway instance, you can just copy all `EventEmitter.prototype` methods onto your function, and then apply the `EventEmitter` to it.

```
function osPreferences() { … }
for (var p in EventEmitter.prototype)
    osPreferences[p] = EventEmitter.prototype[p];
EventEmitter.call(osPreferences);
```

> Is it worth trying to mimic the inherited vs non-inherited setup?

Not really. You insist on a singleton usage of your api, so you don't need any inheritance at all.

> Are there any weird cases to take into account, given that the default `this` would be changed?

No, [`EventEmitter` is coded quite defensively](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js). Of course, your listeners might find it unusual…

Answer (score 1):

Looping through and copying the methods and properties of the original object can fail depending on how EventEmitter is implemented. This approach is most likely to fail when there is heavy use of closures to hide properties.

The best approach, in my opinion, is to just directly set the prototype on your function instance. With your example, it would be something like:

```js
var OSPreferences = function(){
  // ...
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(OSPreferences, new EventEmitter());
```

Comment: And if you want it to work in the browser as well, you can fall back to the `__proto__` property for browsers that don't support setPrototypeOf() yet.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was worrying about, but wasn't sure how much of a real issue it is. Based on Bergi's answer, it appears that EventEmitter shouldn't generally give me any problems, as currently implemented. But it's still an interesting problem in general. I know setPrototypeOf has a performance impact, do you know of any solid data on that? (how bad it tends to be, etc.)

Comment: @SethHolladay, I wouldn't worry about setPrototypeOf's performance since you're only calling it once for your singleton. If I were to worry, I'd maybe worry about the cost of method invocation up the prototype chain vs. on the object itself. To find the answer, I'd recommend that you create a jsPerf test  like http://jsperf.com/scope-chain-lookup-vs-prototype-chain-lookup/3

Comment: What I would worry most here is that despite `typeof OSPreferences == "function"` some things like `OSPreferences.call()`/`apply`/`bind` don't work any more. Which throws off a lot of programs.

Comment: Right, of course. Yikes. Sometimes the world just doesn't work the way you want. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

[ES6 class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is the most elegant solution for subclassing.

```
let EventEmitter = require('events'); //or `require('events').EventEmitter` in nodejs
Class osPreferences extends EventEmitter{
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log(this);
    }
}
let osp = new osPreferences();
osp.on('change',function(){
    console.log('osPreferences changed');
});
osp.emit('change');
```

Unfortunately, latest Node version does not support class syntax. You have to use [iojs](https://iojs.org/en/index.html) instead.

Comment: This looks good for people that want their API to be a constructor. Unfortunately, that would be very confusing for my use case, since `osPreferences` might be a getter or setter depending on the type of arguments it is given, perhaps being a shortcut to other functions, and has the potential to save data to the disk, etc. It's meant to be a shortcut, not a class.

Comment: I still recommend you to redesign your code structure and use class syntax instead of applying any other solutions.